# Spring-boot error: Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, entitymanager

I am running my Spring Boot application but it gives me this error related with the `EntityManagerFactory`. Should I create my own `EntityManager`? Isn't it included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

```
2018-08-21 12:27:18.993  WARN 2728 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'office365InstanceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'instanceRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'office365InstanceRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#252a8aae' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#252a8aae': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2018-08-21 12:27:19.018  INFO 2728 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-21 12:27:19.071 ERROR 2728 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

Description:

```
Field instanceRepository in com.qualityclouds.qcforoffice365.service.Office365InstanceServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.2</version>
    </dependency>



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Qcforoffice365Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Qcforoffice365Application.class, args);

        Driver driver = (Driver) ctx.getBean("QCDriver");

        driver.run();

    }
}


@Repository
public interface Office365InstanceRepository extends CrudRepository<Office365InstanceConfiguration, String> {

}

@Service
public class Office365InstanceServiceImpl implements Office365InstanceService {

    @Autowired
    private Office365InstanceRepository instanceRepository;

    @Override
    public Office365InstanceConfiguration findById(String id) {
        return instanceRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

}
```

Here is the [package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cQVs.png)

Comment: Remove @EnableJpaRepositories

Comment: When I remove it, it doesn't find the repository itself:



Description:

Field instanceRepository in com.qualityclouds.qcforoffice365.service.Office365InstanceServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.qualityclouds.qcforoffice365.repository.Office365InstanceRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.qualityclouds.qcforoffice365.repository.Office365InstanceRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: How does your package structure look like? Make sure that Qcforoffice365Application is above the rest.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have added the structure to the post. Yes, the application is above all.

Comment: What is EsConfig?

Comment: It is an ElasticSearch configuration file

Comment: stupid question: do you have the data source configured?

Comment: I just have those properties in the application.properties file.

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qcdb
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for that. I just needed to delete the repository in .m2 and try it again. Guess it was something related with some dependencias from other projects.